# Half paired t-test?

Tags: correlation, t-test, paired-data

I have data where all individuals have an observation at time 1, but then only half of the individuals have an observation at time 2, and I want to compare the means of times 2 and 1. Is a standard t-test the way to go here, despite the outcomes obviously being not independent due to half of the individuals contributing data to both times, or is there a more efficient approach that handles this correlation and also uses the fact that we only have 1 observation for half of the individuals?

Comment: If you lack data for half the individuals, how could you possibly use them for your testing?  Are you perhaps hinting that you have observations at times *other* than time 2 for the remaining individuals? If so, you could exploit that *provided you have a model for how the results vary over time.*

Comment: The individuals with only a single observation do provide *some* information, if we assume equal residual standard deviation at each time point, because they tell us something about about the standard deviation at time 1. Intuition and some very rough simulations suggest this won't make enough of a difference to worry about unless this standard deviation is very high.

Comment: You should supply a bit more information. Are the individuals that do and don't supply a second reading random subsets of the same overall population? Were they all intended to have a second observation, or do they come from different studies? How many datapoints do you have for time 1 and time 2?

Comment: @MichaelLew this is a controlled experiment, where we have a sample of mice, measure their outcome on day 1, and then half of these mice are sacrificed to obtain other measurements, while the other half live until time 2 in which the same outcome is measured again. We have 32 total measurements at time 1 and 16 at time 2.

Comment: How are the sacrificed half selected?

Comment: Further to @Glen_b's question, you should note that haphazard sampling is not random sampling. When you say how the mice were split into the two groups explain the actual selection mechanism. (I'm a retired pharmacologist, so I know how 'randomly selected' animals often are not.)